# Best practices and some doubts regarding RESTful APIs authorisation

Tags: node.js, rest, oauth-2.0, jwt, authorization

I'm currently developing a backend server in Express.js where users can log in or register on the client side using either a basic email and password method or a social sign-in method (e.g., Google, Facebook). During my research, I came across two potential approaches: JWTs (JSON Web Tokens) and OAuth 2.0. I have a few questions regarding this:

1. Should I use JWTs for authorization, OAuth 2.0, or a combination of
   both?
2. If I opt for JWTs, what are the best practices for validating
   them on the server side? Is it sufficient to verify them with the
   secret key, or are there other recommended practices?
3. If I choose OAuth 2.0, do I need to create my own proxy authorization server to
   manage users who register using email and password instead of
   third-party social accounts?
4. Are there any other authorization
   techniques commonly used at the production level to ensure robust
   security?

Additionally, recommend any learning resources or materials that would be beneficial in understanding these concepts?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's common to use JWT (JSON Web Tokens) in conjunction with OAuth 2.0 for different aspects of authentication and authorization. Here's a common scenario:

OAuth 2.0 for Authentication:
Use OAuth 2.0 to handle the initial authentication flow, especially for scenarios like social sign-ins (e.g., Google, Facebook).
When a user logs in using a third-party identity provider (OAuth 2.0 authentication server), your server receives an authorization code.
Exchange this authorization code for an access token and possibly a refresh token.
The access token can then be used to access the user's resources on the third-party service.
JWT for Authorization:
Once your server has authenticated the user (either through OAuth 2.0 or another method like email/password), you can generate a JWT to represent the user's identity and associated claims.
The JWT can include information such as user roles, permissions, and other relevant details.
This JWT can be sent to the client, and the client can include it in the headers of subsequent requests to your API.
Your server can then validate the JWT to ensure that the request is authorized based on the contained claims.
By combining OAuth 2.0 and JWTs, you leverage OAuth 2.0 for the initial authentication flow and JWTs for managing authorization and access control within your application.

Here's a simplified flow:

User logs in via OAuth 2.0 (e.g., Google, Facebook).
Your server obtains an access token from the OAuth 2.0 provider.
Your server generates a JWT containing user claims (roles, permissions).
This JWT is sent to the client.
The client includes the JWT in the headers of API requests.
Your server validates the JWT to authorize the request.
This approach provides a good balance of industry-standard authentication (OAuth 2.0) and a flexible, stateless authorization mechanism (JWT). It's worth noting that the specific details can vary based on your application requirements and the identity provider you're integrating with.